# Profile is created but account info not found?

Tags: nem

I start catapult service using docker.

I created two profile successfully.

I run this command `nem2-cli profile list` I can see the two profiles.

but when I run this command `nem2-cli account info`, I get this error:

```
processing.. |ERR To start using the nem2-cli create a default profile using: nem2-cli profile create --privatekey your_private_key --network network --url http://localhost:3000.
```

---

I add in the `--profile`, now it works. But, before this without specify the `--profile`, it will automatically return the 1st profile.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a bug in the software. I would suggest creating an issue for the developers to look at. https://github.com/nemtech/nem2-cli